# Correct notation for Continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume two random variables $X \in \mathcal{X}$ and $Y \in \mathcal{Y}$. Then, if $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables

$P(X \in E) = \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} P(X \in E, Y=y)$.

I want to know what the correct notation is if $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables. Is this correct?
$P(X \in E) = \int_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} P(X \in E, Y\in (y,y+dy])$ or it should be $P(X \in E) = \int_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} P(X \in E, Y\in (y,y+dy])dy$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by $P (Y\in (y,y+dy))$.  If you mean the actual probability that $Y$ falls between $y$ and $dy$, then the extra factor of $dy$ would be unnecessary, but this would be practically impossible to calculate.  If however you mean the pdf of $Y$ for a given value of $y$, then you would need the extra $dy$ at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ have a joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, then
$$ \mathbb P(X \in E) = \int_{E} dx\; \int_{\mathcal Y} dy\; f_{X,Y}(x,y)$$
More generally, their joint distribution is a probability measure $\mu_{X,Y}$ on $\mathcal X \times \mathcal Y$, and $\mathbb P(X \in E) = \mu_{X,Y}(E \times \mathcal Y) = \int_{E \times \mathcal Y} d\mu_{X,Y}$.